# <include> tag isn't accurately displaying it's content

Tags: android, include

I have a layout menu which contains this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/computersMenu"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp">
        <include        layout="@layout/component_add_button"
                        android:id="@+id/imagebutton_add_client"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

component_add_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Looking at the preview (**EDIT**: I mean the "Graphical Layout" tab of the xml editor in eclipse which uses the same rendering engine as all devices AFAIK) of component_add_button.xml you can see the image. Great. On the page which is including it it isn't displaying (although it does give you a selectable space where the image should be).

This seems like a really simple example that "should just work". The include tag has always seemed really flaky to me - I'm wondering if I'm missing something in terms of how it actually works...?

Comment: If you mean the ADT UI designer inside eclipse with "preview" - Test your layout on a real device or emulator. The tools have improved, but they are still not useable imho. Lot's of things don't get displayed correctly, include sounds like a candidate for that as well.

Comment: I can confirm that preview in ADT did not nest previews last time I looked

Comment: remove the id part from include tag and place it in ImageView.

Comment: @alextsc, @Merlin You should be able to trust the "Graphical Layout" pane as it uses the same renderer as the device. @YashwanthKumar - According to [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) document id/width/height are the only attributes of include which are optional & have an effect by overriding the same values of the root `ViewGroup` of the target layout.

Comment: Yes we should. But at least I don't, because I've seen plenty of times that it displays things wrong. At that point, the explanation why that can't be is moot - it's not correct, that is a fact. Theorycrafting does not help me from there. I use it only for quick and dirty previews. In doubt, test on a real device. Did you do that btw? :)

Comment: You were totally right - After writing that you **should** be able to trust it I thought to myself "I know better than to trust in statements which contain the word 'should'". On devices it worked fine.

Comment: Yep, i wish those tools would be more reliable, but that will take some time. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your answer states, the eclipse preview does not display included layouts.

The simplest way to avoid doubt or mistakes in markup when "including" layout's is to design in the original layout then right click the view you wish to extract and select *Extract include...* from the menu

Answer (score 0):

On a device this functionality worked fine. This seems like a bug in the "Graphical Layout" tab of the layout xml editor shipped with android-sdk.